# RecyclerView Image background change randomly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imageview, android-cardview

I've implemented a `RecyclerView` with `CardView`. Each `CardView` has an `ImageView` which I want to change its background color depending on the result of a Query (Empty result set -> Grey / Non Empty result set -> Red), this is implemented on the `onBindViewHolder` of the `RecyclerView Adapter`.

Here's the Adapter's Code (I've removed most of the code for the sake of clarity):

```
public class FavDirsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FavDirsAdapter.FavDirsViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private Context mContext;
    private int range;
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    public FavDirsAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, FragmentManager fm) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mCursor = cursor;
        mContext = context;
        range = cursor.getCount();
        mFragmentManager = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public FavDirsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_fav_dirs_list, parent, false);
        return new FavDirsViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final FavDirsViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            viewHolder.favDirsItemTextView.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(
                    (FilmoContract.FavDirEntry.COLUMN_DIR))));
            getDirImage(viewHolder);
            setScheduledFilmsColor(viewHolder);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return range;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    class FavDirsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView favDirsItemTextView;
        ImageView favDirsItemImageView;
        ImageView favDirsItemScheduledFilmsImage;

        public FavDirsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            favDirsItemTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fav_dirs_item_text_view);
            favDirsItemImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fav_dirs_item_image_view);
            favDirsItemScheduledFilmsImage =
                    (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fav_dirs_item_scheduled_films_image_button);
        }
    }

    private void setScheduledFilmsColor(FavDirsViewHolder viewHolder) {
        new SetScheduledFilmsColor(viewHolder, mContext).execute();
    }

    private void getDirImage (FavDirsViewHolder viewHolder) {
        new FetchFavDirsImage(viewHolder, mContext).execute();
    }
}
```

The adapter receive a `Cursor` with a Films Director data list stored on a `DB`. Then assign each row data to a `ViewHolder` fileds.

Then I make an additional query to determine wheter each Director has movies scheduled soon, and depending on the query result, color the `ImageView` (favDirsItemScheduledFilmsImage) background.

I tried first to make the query on the `onBindViewHolder` Adapter's method, but I've found that all the `ImageViews`, where colored in the same color (Grey). So since there is a `DB Query` involved, I've tried to create an `AsyncTask` (SetScheduledFilmsColor) to do all that stuff. Here's the code:

```
public class SetScheduledFilmsColor extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private ImageView mImageButton;
    private String mDirName;
    private Context mContext;

    boolean scheduledFilms;

    static final String[] PROGRAM_COLUMNS = {
            FilmoContract.FilmEntry._ID,
            FilmoContract.FilmEntry.COLUMN_DATE,
            FilmoContract.FilmEntry.COLUMN_TIME,
            FilmoContract.FilmEntry.COLUMN_CYCLE,
            FilmoContract.FilmEntry.COLUMN_TITLE,
    };

    public SetScheduledFilmsColor(FavDirsAdapter.FavDirsViewHolder viewHolder, Context context) {
        mImageButton = viewHolder.favDirsItemScheduledFilmsImage;

        //mImageButton = new ImageButton(mContext);
        mDirName = viewHolder.favDirsItemTextView.getText().toString();
        mContext = context;
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Uri filmoDirector = FilmoContract.FilmEntry.buildProgramUriWithDirector();

        Cursor tempCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
                filmoDirector,
                PROGRAM_COLUMNS,
                mDirName,
                null,
                null
        );

        scheduledFilms = tempCursor.moveToFirst();
        tempCursor.close();
        return scheduledFilms;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean scheduledFilms) {
        super.onPostExecute(scheduledFilms);
        mImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_new_releases_white_24dp);
        if (scheduledFilms) {
            //mImageButton.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            mImageButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(
                    mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.lafilmo_color), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY
            );
        } else {
            //mImageButton.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            mImageButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(
                    mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.dividers), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I'm changing the color in the `onPostExecute` method. However, even doing this `asynchronously`, it doesn't matter the query result (I'm sure the query and the `onPostExecute` condition are fine, I have debug that). Even more, each time I reload the `RecyclerView` `Fragment` while navigating through my App, the colored `ImageViews` are different each time.

I don't understand, how `RecyclerView` can maintain the reference correctly to the other `CardView` fields (the fileds on the `viewHolder`, like favDirsItemTextView or favDirsItemImageView) which are assigned on the `onBindViewHolder`, and not maintain a reference to the colored `ImageView` (favDirsItemScheduledFilmsImage).

Can anybody shed some light on this? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Finally I solved this using different drawable resources (Same image but different colors). Now it works perfectly. I use a drawable resource in grey for empty queries result sets, and another white drawable with the same image to which I can now apply the red color filter in case of not empty queries result sets.

However, it would be nice to understand why this happens when you use the same drawable resource applying to it different color filters. It completely has no sense for me.